# Angular - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular

I have this code in my authentication service:

```js
export class AuthenticationService {
  private token!: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient , private router: Router) {}
  logout() {
    this.http.get < {
        access_token: string,
        expiresIn: number
      } > (BACKEND_URL + '/logout')
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.token = null;
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
        this.authStatusListener.next(false);
        clearTimeout(this.tokenTimer);
        this.clearAuthData();
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        console.log(response);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

}
```

I got this error:

> error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

> 92         this.token = null;

The error is in the logout()

I changed it to:

```
this.token! = null;
```

But its still unresolved

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is compile time error because your declaration syntax is wrong.

Change,

```
private token!: string;   // This is not the right syntax to say token will not be type of string
```

to,

```
private token: string;
```

OR

```
private token = null
```

OR

```
private token = '';
```

Whichever is suitable in your case.

Comment: When I changed it to private token: string;  I got this error:   error TS2564: Property 'token' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

16   private token: string;

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens because you are using the operator "!". It means that your variable never will be null.

What you need to do is just remove the symbol after the variable if you want to set null!

```js
private token: string = null
```

You can read more here: [Documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator)

Comment: When I changed it to private token: string;  I got this error:   error TS2564: Property 'token' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

16   private token: string;

Comment: Now you can initialize with null or opened string: private token: string = null or private token: string = ''

Answer (score 0):

The "!" syntax exists for those cases where you can't guarantee that the value will be defined immediately. It's an escape hatch, and shouldn't be relied on, as it can make your code less safe. A default value is usually preferred.
Use

```
private token = '';
```

instead of

```
private token!: string;
```